# C# How to disable pan interaction in Windows Phone 8.1 map control?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, maps

I need to specifically disable the pan interaction in Windows Phone 8.1 map control but not other interactions (zoom, rotate, etc). How can I do it in C#?

Thanks for any reply.